# Search data in mongodb according to field values

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, search, filter

I am using mongodb and node.js. In my database i have 6 fields that is

1. bid
2. color (Array)
3. size (Array)
4. cat_id
5. sub_cat_id

All is working fine. Now i want to add filter in my code. In filter area i have add this all fields. user select multiple colors and sizes so it will come in Array format but most of the time user will not select color option or size option at that time field values comes blank so my filter will not take any result from database. so i want to remove color or size field if value is empty during search. I have tried below code but its not working.how i do this.

```
var catId     = new Array();
var sort      = saveFilterSort.sort;
var filter    = req.body;

if(req.body.catId){
  catId.push("category_id:"+req.body.catId);
}

if(req.body.subcatid){
  catId.push("sub_category_id:"+req.body.subcatid);
}

if(req.body.minprice){
  catId.push("price:{$gt:"+req.body.minprice+"}");
}

if(req.body.maxprice){
 catId.push("price:{$lt:"+req.body.maxprice+"}");
}

if(req.body.color){
  catId.push("color:{$in:"+req.body.color+"}");
}

if(req.body.size){
  catId.push("attribute:{$in:"+req.body.size+"}");
}

var finalCat = catId.join(',');

console.log(finalCat);
console.log(catId);


if((filter) && (sort)){ 
    Product.find(
    {
      brand_id:bid, finalCat
    },
    function(error,fetchallFeatProds)
    {
      console.log('#######################');
      console.log(fetchallFeatProds);
      console.log('#######################');
      callback(error,fetchallFeatProds);

    }).sort( {_id:-1,price:-1} );
```

This code is not working. Please help me.

Comment: What is an error?

Comment: `finalCat` is just a string, which certainly won't work as a query since that requires an object

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad its treat like string.see below

Comment: @chridam i agree with you sir check below 

[ 'category_id:57ceb9c3714ba35d22c0f814',
  'sub_category_id:57ceb9cf714ba35d22c0f815',
  'price:{$gt:556}',
  'price:{$lt:677}',
  'attribute:{$in:57bd9b0feb288f99247b23c7,57bd9baaeb288f28067b23c7}' ]

Answer (score 2):

Mongoose find prototype handle json and not string

```
var query     = {brand_id:bid};
var sort      = saveFilterSort.sort;
var filter    = req.body;

if(req.body.catId){
  query.category_id = req.body.catId;
}

if(req.body.subcatid){
  query.sub_category_id = req.body.subcatid;
}

if(req.body.minprice){
 query.price = {$gt:req.body.minprice};
}

if(req.body.maxprice){
  query.price = {$lt:req.body.maxprice};
}

if(req.body.color){
 query.color = {$in:req.body.color};
}

if(req.body.size){
  query.attribute = {$in:req.body.size};
}


if((filter) && (sort)){ 
  Product.find(query, ...
```

Comment: Still its given blank value see below (a) is for my request (b) is in my database value

Comment: (a) : { brand_id: 57bd5cffcebed2a3189cedd0,
  category_id: '57ceb9c3714ba35d22c0f814',
  sub_category_id: '57ceb9cf714ba35d22c0f815',
  price: { '$gt': '677' },
  attribute: { '$in': [ '57bd9b0feb288f99247b23c7', '57bd9baaeb288f28067b23c7' ] } }
#######################
[]
#######################

Comment: (b) 

{

   "brand_id": "57bd5cffcebed2a3189cedd0",
   "sub_category_id": "57ceb9cf714ba35d22c0f815",
   "category_id": "57ceb9c3714ba35d22c0f814",
   "description": "New Jacket",
   "sku": "New-Jacket",
   "name": "New Jacket",
   "_id": ObjectId("57ceba4a714ba35d22c0f818"),
   "attribute"▼: [
     "57bd9b06eb288f27067b23c6",
     "57bd9b0feb288f99247b23c7",
     "57bd9b22eb288f19257b23c6",
     "57bd9b50eb288f9a247b23c7" 
  ],
   "color": [
     "57c562ce3c904bdb14114314",
     "57ceb5f7714ba35d22c0f7f9",
     "57ceb609714ba35d22c0f7fa" 
  ],

}

Comment: have you data corresponding to those filter ? What happend if you enter this request directly in mongo ?

Comment: if i directly hit in database its give me values

Comment: if i remove .sort( {_id:-1,price:-1} ); line then it will work. but i want to add this as well

Comment: Use sort chaining like find(query).sort({_id: -1}).sort({price: -1})